# Opening the camera with Vue + Ionic causes a reload

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, vuejs3, capacitor

I recently asked a question because I was trying to use the "capacitor-community/barcode-scanner" plugin with Ionic + VueJS. but I finally gave up. I can't get it to work.

So I decided to try Ionic Native plugin "https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/barcode-scanner" , w ith the project: "https://github.com/StarleyDev/barcodescanner-sdk31.git" , i managed to make the application compile correctly for Android 11. But look at the this strange behavior, if I call the plugin through the VUE component:

https://streamable.com/ei2lmx

It seems that VUEJS fully reloads right after I call the camera. And even reading the barcode, now that everything has been reloaded, the callbacks don't work. But if I call it directly from the console:

https://streamable.com/0yahnu

Works correctly and doesn't reload the VUEJS, i believe the problem is the same that is causing the Capacitor plugin to malfunction. Any ideias?

I tried calling "SCAN" in several ways, through the BarcodeScanner class, natively through 'window.cordova' and nothing helped me. Same result every time.

Comment: -1


First of the plugin you are using is not a Capacitor plugin, it's a Cordova Plugin. Don't mix the two. Second, there any MANY WORKING tutorials on how to use the barcode scanner plugin for both cordova and capacitor, you just need to google.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.